# Selecionar os dois maiores valores de uma tupla

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma consulta que exibe o seguinte resultado:

```
ID    | v1  | v2 | v3   |
54384 | 2.4 | 8  | 2.55 |
54385 | 5.6 | 1  | 3.24 |
```

Como fazer, em um `SELECT`, a seleção somente dos dois maiores valores entre os campos "v1", "v2" e "v3"?

Resultado assim:

```
ID    | Maior_v1  | Maior_v2 | 
54384 | 8         | 2.55     |
54385 | 5.6       | 3.24     |
```

Existem alguma maneira? Como fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possivel com a utilização das funções `GREATEST` e`LEAST`. Veja a documentação [aqui](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html).

```
SELECT dados.id, max1.valor as maior_v1, max2.valor as maior_v2
FROM dados
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id, GREATEST(v1, v2, v3) as valor FROM dados
) as max1
ON max1.id = dados.id
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id, LEAST(GREATEST(v1, v2), GREATEST(v2, v3), GREATEST(v1, v3)) valor FROM dados
) as max2
ON max2.id = dados.id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27b2ce/14)

Comment: Gostei da lógica de pegar o menor dos maiores.

Answer (score 2):

O MySql tem uma função chamada [`GREATEST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) que retorna o maior valor em uma série de colunas.

O problema nesse caso é encontrar o segundo maior valor. Minha ideia foi de trocar o maior valor pelo menor valor com [`LEAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) através de uma subquery

```
SELECT id, maior, 
    GREATEST(
        if(v1 = m.maior, LEAST(v1, v2, v3), v1), 
        if(v2 = m.maior, LEAST(v1, v2, v3), v2), 
        if(v3 = m.maior, LEAST(v1, v2, v3), v3)
    ) as maior2 
FROM 
(
    SELECT *, GREATEST(v1, v2, v3) as maior FROM new_table
) as m;
```

Exemplo no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfb68/4).

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que haja alguma maneira mais performática, mas com esse conjunto de cases é possível chegar ao resultado:

```
Select
  Notas.ID,
  NOTAS_V1.MaiorV1,
  NOTAS_V1.MaiorV2
FROM
  Notas
  INNER JOIN

    (SELECT 
         N1.ID,
         CASE 
           WHEN (N1.V1 > N1.V2) AND (N1.V1 > N1.V3)  THEN N1.V1
           WHEN (N1.V2 > N1.V1) AND (N1.V2 > N1.V3)  THEN N1.V2
           ELSE N1.V3
         END as MaiorV1,
         CASE 
           WHEN (N1.V1 > N1.V2) AND (N1.V1 > N1.V3)  THEN
             CASE
               WHEN (N1.V2 > N1.V3) THEN N1.V2
               ELSE N1.V3
             END
           WHEN (N1.V2 > N1.V1) AND (N1.V2 > N1.V3)  THEN
             CASE
               WHEN (N1.V1 > N1.V3) THEN N1.V1
               ELSE N1.V3
             END
           ELSE
             CASE
               WHEN (N1.V1 > N1.V2) THEN N1.V1
               ELSE N1.V2
             END
         END as MaiorV2
     FROM NOTAS N1
    ) AS NOTAS_V1 ON (Notas.ID = NOTAS_V1.ID)
```

[Exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce927/33)

Comment: Talvez extrair a lógica para determinar os maiores em uma procedure ?

Comment: Tem a vantagem de ser comparações lógicas no mesmo registro, sem nested loops. Mas ainda assim achei meio feia a query